# Throttle submissions to ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

To prevent an XY problem, I'll first explain the problem I am trying to solve:

### Problem I am trying to solve

I want to send the contents of a MongoDB collection with a size of around
3 million records to a queuing microservice, so that other microservices might subscribe to my topic and read the messages at their convenience. To keep memory usage into bounds, I stream the collection from the database to the code that sends the messages
to the queuing service, and I want to limit the amount of messages that are
being created and sent at any moment to a maximum of 4000. I currently store the messages that need to be sent in a `ArrayBlockingQueue`, and an `ExecutorService` picks them off there. Multiple threads may be using the same code to send other messages of their own, so I need to check if there is any room left in this list, before adding a message to it.

### Minimal example

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;

import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.HOURS;
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS;

public class Main {
    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger();

    private ExecutorService executorService;
    private ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable> messageQueue;
    private int threadCount = 2;
    private int maxMessageQueueSize = 4000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().go();
    }

    private void go() {
        initExecutorService();
        sendMessages();
        shutdownExecutorService();
    }

    private void initExecutorService() {
        messageQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(maxMessageQueueSize);
        executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                threadCount, threadCount, 1L, HOURS, messageQueue);
    }

    private void sendMessages() {
        int fullQueueDetectedCount = 0;

        // simulate the sending of messages to a queue
        for (int i = 0; i < 10_000; i++) {
            if (maxMessageQueueSize - messageQueue.size() > 0) {
                if (fullQueueDetectedCount > 0) fullQueueDetectedCount = 0;
                submitMessage(i);
            } else {
                fullQueueDetectedCount++;
                if (fullQueueDetectedCount > 6) {
                    LOG.error("Queue is full, even after waiting {} times " +
                            "for an empty spot", fullQueueDetectedCount);
                    return;
                }

                if (!sleepBasedOn(fullQueueDetectedCount)) return;

                LOG.info("Slept while waiting for a place on the queue");
            }
        }

        LOG.info("Submitted all messages");
    }

    private boolean sleepBasedOn(int power) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep((long) (1000 * Math.pow(2, power)));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            LOG.error(e);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void shutdownExecutorService() {
        executorService.shutdown();
        try {
            executorService.awaitTermination(2, SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            LOG.error(e);
        }
    }

    private void submitMessage(int num) {

        Runnable sendTask = () -> {
            try {
                LOG.debug("Sending message with number {}", num);
                // simulate the amount of time needed to assemble
                // and send the message to the queueing service
                Thread.sleep(25);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                LOG.error(e);
            }
        };

        BiConsumer<Void, Throwable> logException = (retValue, exception) -> {
            if (exception != null) {
                LOG.error("Failed to submit message");
            }
        };

        try {
            CompletableFuture
                    .runAsync(sendTask, executorService)
                    .whenComplete(logException);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error(e);
        }
    }
}
```

### Question

Is there a better, maybe more efficient or "clean" way to do what I want? Did
I miss any of the built-in `Executors` that do this already or is there
a library? I need all messages to be sent, so I cannot allow messages to be
dropped when the queue is full. Also, although this code example doesn't show
it, I'm running a Spring web application.

Naturally, general remarks about this code are appreciated as well (code style, etc.).

Comment: Is the queue just that? An `ArrayBlockingQueue` in memory? Or does this represent any not-included-here concept? And apart from that: I cannot spot the actual putting things to the queue in your code...

Comment: I send messages to a microservice that queues these messages so that other microservices can pick them up. So in the `sendTask`, the real code would be something like `queuingService.submit(msg)` instead of `Thread.sleep(...)`. The `ArrayBlockingQueue` is just used for storing `Runnable`s that actually submit stuff to this queuing microservice. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, somewhat. If it was just a simple ArrayBlockingQueue, I might have come up with some ideas, but in this case, I am afraid that your question does not match the "real code for review" requirements on codereview. The more senior members of this site would have some ready-made comments with links to "what is on topic here", "how should questions look on codereview" and so on. So, please just take my opinion that this is not suitable for code review and a big "sorry, interesting topic" in prose.